# slate js: how to highlight neighbour components with the same mark on hover?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

```
// utility hook
function useMouseOver() {
  const [mouseOver, setMouseOver] = useState(false);
  return {
    mouseOver,
    triggers: {
      onMouseEnter: () => setMouseOver(true),
      onMouseLeave: () => setMouseOver(false),
    },
  };
}

// mark component
function CommentHighlight({ attributes, children, ...props }) {
  const { mouseOver, triggers } = useMouseOver();
  return (
    <span
      {...attributes}
      {...triggers}
      style={{
        background: mouseOver ? yellow[600] : yellow[200],
        cursor: 'pointer',
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </span>
  );
}
```

Imagine 2 overlapped comments, they have different marks but rendered with the same component `CommentHighlight`:

```
-----
   ---------
aaaccbbbbbbb
```

- `a` - has the mark from comment 1
- `b` - has the mark from comment 2
- `c` - has marks from comments 1 and 2

### When I hover over `aaa` I need `cc` to change color too. But how?

The only guess I have is to track highlight state in redux (or similar) and update every comment component on state change. But this looks like overkill.

Comment: what are the childrens here ?

Comment: inside CommentHighlight? just text (or whatever slate put in here)

Comment: u mean the marks also?

Comment: I don't know how slate internals work and how it deals with marks overlap. `children` is what `slate-react:Editor` provides to components. So it is essentially a black box for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [back, setback] = React.useState(false);
  const changeback = value => {
    setback(value);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CommentHighlight change={back} changeit={e => changeback(e)}>
        aaa
      </CommentHighlight>
      <CommentHighlight change={back} changeit={e => changeback(e)}>
        aaa
      </CommentHighlight>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
function useMouseOver(changeit) {
  const [mouseOver, setMouseOver] = React.useState(false);
  return {
    mouseOver,
    triggers: {
      onMouseEnter: () => {
        setMouseOver(true);
        changeit(true);
      },
      onMouseLeave: () => {
        setMouseOver(false);
        changeit(false);
      }
    }
  };
}

// mark component
function CommentHighlight({ attributes, children, ...props }) {
  const { mouseOver, triggers } = useMouseOver(props.changeit);
  return (
    <span
      {...attributes}
      {...triggers}
      style={{
        background: props.change ? "yellow" : "blue",
        cursor: "pointer"
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </span>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

i dont know if this the approach u looking for but here when u hover on first CommentHighlight the second will change color to and vice versa

Comment: `CommentHighlight` components are govern by slate editor, I can't access them directly. And slatejs is rich text editor https://docs.slatejs.org/